# How to use bufferedreader.readLine in kivy?

Tags: android, python, kivy

Im using kivy + bluetooth socket.

while I'm receiving data from bluetooth, the bufferedreader.read() method works.
But bufferedreader.readLine() method won't work..

```
def change_data(self):
        Logger.info('Im in the change_data!!')
        self.data = 'change_data'

        paired_devices = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices().toArray()
        if BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() == False:
            Logger.info('bluetooth not turned on')
            PythonActivity.mActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE), 200)
        else:
            pass
        for device in paired_devices:
            self.data = str(device.getName())
            Logger.info('Im in the loop!!'+str(device))
            if device.getName() == 'HC-06':

                self.socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString('00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB'))

                break
        if self.socket == None:
            pass
        else:
            self.data = 'connecting'
            self.socket.connect()
def read(self,dt):
        self.recv = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(self.socket.getInputStream()))
        self.data =self.recv.read()
def start(self):
        self.change_data()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.read,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

readLine read IO need data end with \r\n , bluetooth send data need to add end tag with \r\n

Comment: Thanks! I would hav never found the solution if it wasn't your help!!